# How to send the separate orderconfirmation mail for admin and customer

Tags: magento2, module, sales-order, overrides, order-email

I created a custom module to send the separate mail for admin and customer but its not working.could you please suggest me regarding this so i can proceed forward.

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class MyCustomEventObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_inlineTranslation;
    
    public function __construct(
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    ) {
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getData('order');
        $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();
        
        // Send email to customer
        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $templateId = 'your_customer_email_template_id';
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars(['order' => $order])
            ->setFrom('general')
            ->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail())
            ->addBcc('admin@example.com') // add the admin email as a BCC recipient
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
        
        // Send email to admin
        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $templateId = 'your_admin_email_template_id';
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars(['order' => $order])
            ->setFrom('general')
            ->addTo('admin@example.com') // replace with the admin email address
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not send the admin mail to my site please suggest

Comment: Make sure that the email settings in your Magento installation are configured correctly. You can check this by going to Stores > Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses in the Magento Admin panel and verifying that the "Sender Email" and "Sender Name" fields are set correctly

Comment: Sender Email is different from the admin mail I added the adminer mail store>configuration >send a copy to mail and select BCC. to have any idea how I can send the mail copy to the admin

Comment: check the above code . I made some changes .Try it

Comment: ok, you have added the bcc method but I need the bcc mail for the separate email template. please suggest. thanks for helping

Comment: i'm also change the sender email and sender name but still not working mail is not received by admin

Comment: Ensure that there are no conflicts with other extensions or customizations that may be interfering with the email sending process.

Comment: I'm use the other one extension for contact us mail. that's mean they are conflict in your extension.

Comment: Disable any one of the extension and try to find out the problem.

Comment: ok let us try thank you